# Looking through Jest docs and I saw this line of code

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, es6-promise

```
async runTests(
  tests: Array<Test>,
  watcher: TestWatcher,
  onStart: OnTestStart,
  onResult: OnTestSuccess,
  onFailure: OnTestFailure,
  options: TestRunnerOptions,
): Promise<void>
```

What does the `: Promise<void>` part mean/do? What is the purpose?

Comment: It means the function returns a promise, and that the promise doesn't resolve any value

Comment: What is this syntax though  : Promise<void>

Comment: It's Typescript

Comment: I'm curious why you were only confused by the `: Promise<void>`, but thought that the other type annotations, `: Array<Test>`, `: TestWatcher`, `: OnTestStart`, etc. were just fine? Or did your brain fill in curly brackets around the parameters that aren't actually there?

Comment: Yes, exactly that, only now you pointed that out.